# Data from radio button not inserted into db

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

hi i am doing this radio button (like star ratings) for my system. and i've tried everything but my data is not inserted into my database. when i run is doesn't say i have error but when i submit my button it just display the "error in updating data"

this is my radio button code

```
 <legend>Star Rating</legend><br>

    <center>
    <form action="ratingprocess.php" method="post">

Contractor Name: <select name="username"><br>
<option selected>Select Contractor</option>
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fyp");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .     mysqli_connect_error();}
    $sql="SELECT * FROM contractor";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {    
    echo '<option value='.$row['username'].'>'.$row['username'].'</option>';
      }
?>
    </select><br>

<br><br>

    <div class="star">
        <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-1" id="star-1" value="1" />
        <label class="star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-2" id="star-2" value="2" />
        <label class="star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-3" id="star-3" value="3" />
        <label class="star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-4" id="star-4" value="4" />
        <label class="star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-5" id="star-5" value="5" />
        <label class="star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
    </div>

<br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit"> <t> </t>
</center>
</div>
</fieldset> 
</form>
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fyp");
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $rate=$_POST["star"];


   if (!$con)
    {
     die("Cannot execute sql.");
    }
    $update_sql="UPDATE contractor SET star='$rate' WHERE username = '$username'";
    $sql_result=mysqli_query($con,$update_sql);

    if (!$sql_result)
    {
    die ("Error in updating the data");
    }
      else
          echo "Succesfully send the rating.";

?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_error()` is a wonderful function for debugging. You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: hes not vunerable becasue he is using mysqli, we is vunerable becayse he dosen't use it properly. prepared statement is part of mysqli and you cannot use it in some case.

Comment: like @aynber says, mysqli_error(0 is a great tools. From what i see your trying to get a resutl from a select uery. On insert, update, remove and delete, use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php instead.

Comment: This isn't your problem, but I don't like it. Your `form` starts inside the `fieldset` and then ends outside the `fieldset`. As for the problem, I don't know. The code looks fine. I would `echo $update_sql;` and try the query in Workbench